# Joomla 3.2 user registration

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, user-registration

I have a website which allows user registration, but there is a problem when new users register and try to log in for the first time:

1. User registers and chooses a password.
2. User verifies his/her e-mail adress
3. I (admin) recieve an e-mail that I need to approve the user (this is the setting I use). I approve the user.
4. The user receives an e-mail that he/she is now approved.
5. User tries to log in, but this fails. I don't know the error message, but I think its something like "Wrong user name or password".
6. I check User Manager in Joomla Backend, and the user is enabled and activated. Still, the user cannot login.
7. Only after I manually enter a new password for the user in Joomla Backend, the user is able to login. But I don't want to do this for each new user of course...

I have looked all over the joomla forums and the internet, I can't find a solution, and it is crucial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long LONG searches found the solution [here](https://github.com/Skullbock/joomla-cms/commit/dac70c8c023a2cf1079fa8c31fa2ed3dc393f966)

in the file plugins/user/joomla/joomla.php
you need to change line 505
from

```
if ($userPluginParams->get('strong_passwords') == 1)
```

to

```
if ($userPluginParams->get('strong_passwords', 1) == 1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to update to the latest version?
I mean, 3.2 had this issue (we suffered it too) and a hotfix was released. It is always better to update than hacking the core.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try to update your version to 3.2.7, it helped me.

Comment: It's the sane thing to do! :)